# convergence of series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

how do you determine if a series converges or diverges? Do you just look at their behavior?

Comment: This seems to come from a textbook.  Just before this there should be some explanation and examples computed of similar type.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
For (a), calculate the limit of general term $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{n^3-1}{\sqrt{n^6+n^2}}}$ and use the necessary condition for convergence.
For (b) also use the necessary condition.

Comment: whats the necessary condition?

Comment: If series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ converges then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{a_n}=0.$

Comment: can it be used the other way around, that if the limit equals 0 the series converges?

Comment: In general, no. $\dfrac{1}{n}\to{0}$ however the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{n}}$ is divergent.

Comment: How do you find the general term?

Comment: For the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ its _general term_ is $a_n.$